# Type mismatch compilation error with tuple

Tags: f#

The [Tour of f#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/fsharp/tour) has a sample similar to this code:

```
let swap_tuple (a, b) = (b, a)

let result = swap_tuple ("one", "two") 
printfn "%A" result // prints ("two", "one")
```

So the code above work. But why does this code:

```
let swap_tuple (a, b) = (b, a)
printfn "%A" swap_tuple ("one", "two")
```

throws this compilation error:

```
error FS0001: 
Type mismatch. Expecting a     'a -> 'b -> 'c  but given a   'a -> unit     
The type ''a -> 'b' does not match the type 'unit'
```

What is wrong in the second version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your second version, your format string has just the one format specifier, but the printfn statement has been suppplied with two. You need to use () to group together swap_tuple with its arguments into a single argument.

```
let swap_tuple (a, b) = (b, a)

printfn "%A" (swap_tuple ("one", "two") )
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Jimmy's answer, you could also use the pipeline operators:

```
printfn "%A" <| swap_tuple ("one", "two")
```

or

```
("one", "two")
|> swap_tuple
|> printfn "%A"
```